# Form submit in angularJS directive

Tags: angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a custom directive(contentData) for creating a custom form in my application. which have a template file. This template file have multiple piece of data which is control by a JOSN file.

I am trying to send from data to my controller by clicking on submit button but i am able to do that.

```
[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/aB221u18ccNMHfJbOFDo?p=preview)
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to add scope:false in the directive definition so that when any value get change inside the directive the same is reflected in the parent scope. I have added scope to false in the plnkr and the $scope.templateVariable was reflected in the parent scope.

```
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope:false,
    templateUrl :'template.html',
    // NB: no isolated scope!!
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        //console.log(attrs.yourname);
        // executes the expression on the current scope returning the result
        // and adds it to the scope
        scope.variable = scope.$eval(attrs.yourDirective);
        console.log(scope.variable);
       // scope.myfn=function(){
        //  scope.templateVariable='hello world';
        //}
    },
    // the variable is available in directive controller,
    // and can be fetched as done in link function
    controller: ['$scope', '$element', '$attrs',
        function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
            $scope.myfn = function(){
             $scope.templateVariable='hello world';
            //  $scope.templateVariable = $scope.infogain;
            };
            // executes the expression on the current scope returning the result
            // and adds it to the scope

            //console.log($scope.variable);
        }
     ]
};
```

[Working Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/8SMIk4khstI7L9iuI1NA?p=preview)